# Ionic build command

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, apk, ionic-cli

i have same problem whit the command:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

the process termined with successfull and it create  the apk.
if i send the apk on my smartphone, it see the file same zip and not install

The app work all right, and i can test it with

```
ionic cordova run android
```

but  i can not generate the apk.

```
My configuration:
Ionic 6.18.2
gradle 7.4
node 16.14.0
npm 8.3.1
java 1.8.0_321
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'it see the file same zip and not install'?

Comment: On the mobile phone, if I open the app, the installation does not start, but I am asked how I want to extract the file

Comment: Are you sure it's an apk file? What phone are you trying on? Have you enabled installation from of the 3rd party (unknown sorce) software?

Comment: i created the apk file with the command (https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build)
`ionic cordova build android `
i tryed with --release but not still work
i'm testing on xiaomi and honor with enabled installation from of the 3rd party (unknown sorce) software